# Can I use multiple names for a Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes, one communicates with a specific service `X` by doing http requests to `http://X:9999`. `X` here is the application name. I wonder, can one add multiple names, or alias, to which it will point to `http://X:9999`? I.e can I forward/point `http://Y:9999` to `http://X:9999`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Answer

Yes you can have multiple hostnames point to the same Pod(s).

You can achieve this by creating multiple Services with the same label selectors.

### Background

A service creates endpoints to Pod IPs based on label selectors.

Services will match their selectors against Pod labels.

If multiple Services (with different names) have the same label selectors, they will create multiple endpoints to the same Pods.

### Example

First service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx1
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
...
```

Second service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx2
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
...
```

Each Service will create an endpoint pointing to any Pods with the label `app: nginx`.

So you could hit the same Pods using `nginx2:<port>` and `nginx1:<port>`.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Do you know if it is possible without creating multiple services?

Comment: Not possible without an Ingress Controller like nginx or Kong deployed. You would have to define an Ingress resource mapping both hostnames to the same underlying Service. If you prefer, I could write an answer as to how to do it with Ingress.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the answer, it will work for me:)

Comment: Sorry, new question here. I also deploy with some kind of ingress.yaml where I see the name `X` is define. Do you know if I somehow there can use multiple names?

Comment: Bit hard to explain in comment but - you can define multiple `ingress.spec.rules` which specify hostnames (like nginx1, nginx2). You could have 2 rules that point to the same underlying ClusterIP Service. Note that if you don't have DNS external to your cluster which points to the Ingress Controller, your requests would have to use Ingress Controller Service IP and specify a host header `Host: nginx1`. Hope this makes sense.